# Vector problem (line on a plane)

Tags: vector-spaces

For which values of $a$ and $b$ is this line 
$$\vec{r}= \begin{pmatrix} 3\\2\\a \end{pmatrix}+\lambda \begin{pmatrix} 2\\b\\1\end{pmatrix} $$ 
inside of the plane $x-y+2z=11$ ?

I'm totally missing the approach.

Comment: Hint to get you started: What happens if $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: Then we have the first vector pointing onto the line (position vector) Not sure how that helps me though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint 1: As Cameron noted, setting $\lambda = 0$ gives you the point $(3,2,a)$ which must be on the line and therefore inside the plane. This should allow you to solve for $a$.

Hint 2: The vector $(2,b,1)$ denotes movement along the line. If the line is in the plane, then this vector must be orthogonal to the plane. If you had, say, a normal vector to the plane, you could then apply the idea that $\vec{A} \perp \vec{B}$ iff $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The vector in the direction of the line, $(2,b,1)$ must be orthogonal to the normal to the plane, $(1,-1,2)$, this gives $2-b+2=0$ so $b=4$.

further $(3,2,a)$ must lie in the plane and this gives $a=5$.

Comment: Thanks so far, how do I convert the plane equation to acutual vectors though? I know how to get the normal vector.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking.

Comment: try to change equation $x-y+2z=11$ to a standard form of equation of plane in terms of general position vector 'dot' normal vector = scalar. $r=(x,y,z), n=(1,-1,2), scalar=11$

Comment: You have it in your comment.